Picture Property in Access VBA
Problem With Picture Property
I just want to delete current Picture by clicking button, I know how to do it , but there is error in my code when run doesn't recognize the picture Property
I knew The code but not working
Me.image1.Picture = ""
I tried to do something like CTRL + Space after image control name. I don't find Picture in the list
but there is other picture Property as Image I uploaded ,.Picture_
The Error While I clicked on the button this message Appear Alert code error and force me to be insert mode before [.] of Picture
I am using image as attachment not OLE object
I make sure about my library is checked .
I searched the problem is from MS access object 16.0
This is my library settings in VBA 
I'm using the Access 2019
I thought when I activated MS access object will solve the problem , but that's not solved my problem

You can clear the picture by using the property PictureData:
Me!image1.PictureData = Null


I don't think that answers the question. As the OP notes "I am using image as attachment not OLE object" my best guess is that they're trying to delete an attachment from a record, which would be a duplicate, but the question is unclear to me.

I put this note I'm new in VBA , I don't know if there different between attachment or OLE object in code, and I want to delete photo even there is no duplicate like I put phtoto in wrong record , I have problem in picture property

Me!image1.PictureData = Null
the alert Compile error
Method or data member not found

Then it is not a picture control. Sorry, but your question is unclear also to me.
